# Overriding same method twice from same class

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I was understanding how iterator() method works with ArrayList class  . In ArrayList class I found iterator() method overridden twice from same class AbstractList .

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();         // Itr is an inner private class of 
                               //   ArrayList which 
                              // implements Iterator interface .
}

public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return listIterator();
    }
```

But how is this possible ? There should be an error here of already defined . I am confused .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `iterator()` method you see belongs to the `ArrayList` class, but the second does not.

It belongs to the `SubList` class, which is an inner class of `ArrayList`:

```
private class SubList extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess {
    ...
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return listIterator();
    }
    ...
}
```

Therefore it is not overridden twice by the same class. Each class overrides it once.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the same method twice from **same** class is **not** allowed. In your case, these are two different classes, namely:

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
private class SubList extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess
```

and the latter is an inner class of the former, that's why both can have same method with same signature.